# how to change UIViewController in a Tab of TabBarController

Tags: iphone, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I have an iPhone app with TabBar and tabs. Each tab is loaded with UIViewControllers, what I want for a particular tab is to change UIViewController associated with tab. When I call PresentViewController it changes UIViewController but also hides the TabBar which i dont want.

Can anybody please explain what needs to be done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITabBarController keeps a collection of it's view controllers in a property aptly named `viewControllers`.  You can modify this at runtime.  There are side effects that probably are fine for your app, [but read the docs to be sure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/viewControllers).

A convenience method (and illustration of how to modify that immutable array) would look like this:

```
- (void)replaceTabBarViewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index with:(UIViewController *)newVC {

    NSMutableArray *newVCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];

    if (index < newVCs.count) {
        newVCs[index] = newVC;
        self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:newVCs];
    }
}
```

Call this with the new vc instead of presenting it.

Comment: Thanks worked like charm just a small mod  NSMutableArray *newVCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers]

Comment: dahn can you explain why tab bar image disappears after i load view using above said method ? I changed view two times second time it disappeared and tab became blank.

Comment: Ok Dahn solved the issue forgot to load image in each view for the tab